# Saving Python dictionary as JSON file using Kafka and NiFi

Tags: python, json, apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I am attempting to send JSON data from Python, through Kafka, to a NiFi container where it will be saved. The Python script is below:

```json
server_address = "foobar:1234"
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=server_address)
data = {"type": "record", "name": "CSV", "namespace": "nifi", "fields": {"Id": 0, "Value": 10.1}}
producer.send("outputs", json.dumps(data, default=json_util.default).encode("utf-8"))
producer.flush()
```

The NiFi flow consists of the processors: `ConsumeKafka_2_6` -> `ConvertRecord` -> `PutFile`. I have already validated that the `ConsumeKafka` and `PutFile` processors work without `ConvertRecord`(though the format isn't correct). For the `ConvertRecord` processor, the `RecordReader` is *JsonTreeReader* and the `RecordWriter` is a `CSVRecordSetWriter`. Both are using `AvroSchemaRegistry`, where the schema I've selected is:

```json
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "CSV",
  "namespace": "nifi",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "Id", "type": "int"},
    {"name": "Value", "type": "float"}
  ]
}
```

The data is flowing successfully from the ConsumeKafka processor to the ConvertRecord processor, but from there, it is routed to failure.
My question is, how do I make the entire flow successful? I have found various sources online, but have not been able to get it to work for myself.

**EDIT**: Despite the mess in line 3 of my Python script, I really just want to transfer

```json
"Id": 0, "Value": 10.1
```

Comment: Your Python code isn't using the Schema Registry, so NiFi doesn't need it. Also CSV Writer will not write the field names at all.